# Problem in the Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I have the following Differential equation which I need to solve:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d^2} y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}
= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\right)^2$$

I know how to solve a second order linear differential equations but this is something strange equation which I have seen before while practicing the Differential equation Chapter. Please tell me how to go about solving this Differential equation problem. Any intial hint would do for me.

Thanks

Comment: let $v = \frac {dy}{dt}.$  Now you have a first order differential equation.  $\frac {dv}{dt} = v^2$

Comment: You should probably see how to solve non-linear differential equations and then come back to this one

Comment: @DougM I understood your point. After solving, this gives $\frac{-1}{v}=t+c$ for the Differential equation $\frac{dv}{dt}=v^2$. Should we again substitute, the value of p into the Differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $v$, after differentiating w.r.to $x$ you get  $\frac{dv}{dx}$ = $v^2$

then $\frac{-1}{v}$ = $x+C$

or, $v$ = $\frac{-1}{x+C}$

so $\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $\frac{-1}{x+C}$

$y$ = $-ln(x+C)$ + K